# Erlang Jinterface node nameserver problems on windows

Tags: server, erlang, jinterface

I am trying to implement an interface for my erlang program using jinterface. When I call the command OtpNode otpNode = new OtpNode(nodeName, cookie); java throws an IOException with

java.io.IOException: Nameserver not responding on DESKTOP-GIR29G3 when publishing javanode.

It doesn't seem to be  common problem for people as I couldn't find anything similar online. It's a local node with the node name being "javanode" with no fullstops or dashes. Why would there be a DNS issue on a local node?

I have tried starting an erlang node in the directory the java program is started as well as starting the erlang console on my pc, but I'm very new to erlang so those were just wild guesses that some erlang VM must be running.

Here is the code that may help:

```
   public Erlterface()
    {

        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                setupMBox();
            }
        });
        t.start();

    }

    private void setupMBox()
    {
        try {
            String nodeName = "javanode";
            String cookie = "jinterface";

           //String[] names = OtpEpmd.lookupNames();
           OtpNode otpNode = new OtpNode(nodeName, cookie); //CRASH HAPPENS HERE
            OtpMbox Mbox = otpNode.createMbox("javaserver");
```

The error from the console:

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:54025', transport: 'socket'
java.io.IOException: Nameserver not responding on DESKTOP-GIR29G3 when publishing javanode
    at com.stellar.base.schedule.com.ericsson.otp.erlang.OtpEpmd.r4_publish(OtpEpmd.java:344)
    at com.stellar.base.schedule.com.ericsson.otp.erlang.OtpEpmd.publishPort(OtpEpmd.java:141)
    at com.stellar.base.schedule.com.ericsson.otp.erlang.OtpNode$Acceptor.publishPort(OtpNode.java:784)
    at com.stellar.base.schedule.com.ericsson.otp.erlang.OtpNode$Acceptor.<init>(OtpNode.java:776)
    at com.stellar.base.schedule.com.ericsson.otp.erlang.OtpNode.init(OtpNode.java:232)
    at com.stellar.base.schedule.com.ericsson.otp.erlang.OtpNode.<init>(OtpNode.java:196)
    at com.stellar.base.schedule.com.ericsson.otp.erlang.OtpNode.<init>(OtpNode.java:149)
    at com.stellar.base.schedule.Erlterface.setupMBox(Erlterface.java:40)
    at com.stellar.base.schedule.Erlterface.access$000(Erlterface.java:16)
    at com.stellar.base.schedule.Erlterface$1.run(Erlterface.java:26)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Thanks in advance

Dale

---

UPDATE ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

I went into a dive to try and figure out where exactly the train leaves the rails but I'm taking wild guesses as to what I should flag as potential issues. I just want to add some additional information here to help:

In OptEpmd the following is caught before the io exception is thrown

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

The final source is the native DeulSocketImpl class that I suppose calls on windows to do the final connection thingamabob ad it fails:

static native int connect0(int var0, InetAddress var1, int var2) throws IOException;

Am I missing something in setting up the erlang node? I surely don't have to start it manually? I've diabled my firewall completely to test it. How do I figure out why the connection was refused?